# How to calculate this improper integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

The problem is to solve this integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos^3x}{x^2+1}\mathrm dx$$

I have an idea that use this formula:
$$\cos3x=4 \cos^3x -3\cos x$$

It might be possible to split the above integral into two parts, and for each of these integrals the Feynman integral can be calculated separately by introducing the parameter

$$I(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos ax}{x^2+1}\mathrm dx$$

or
$$I(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-ax}\frac{\cos x}{x^2+1}\mathrm dx$$

Also I wonder if the Residue Theorem could be used to solve this integral.

Comment: Maybe that you meant $\cos(3x)=4\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x)$.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos  You're right, I made a mistake in my typing here.

Comment: I think with second method, you can find $I^{''}(a) + I(a) =$ some doable integral. you can try to solve the DE

Comment: In general \begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos^{2n+1}x}{x^2+1}dx=\frac\pi{4^n}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n+1}k e^{-(2n+1-2k)}
\end{align}

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 9):

Your idea is fine. For each real number $a>0$ and each real number $x$, $\cos(ax)=\operatorname{Re}(e^{iax})$, and therefore\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm dx&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{e^{iax}}{x^2+1}\right)\,\mathrm dx\\&=\operatorname{Re}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{iax}}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm dx\right)\\&=\operatorname{Re}\left(2\pi i\operatorname{res}_{z=i}\frac{e^{iaz}}{z^2+1}\right)\\&=\operatorname{Re}\left(2\pi i\times\left(-\frac12ie^{-a}\right)\right)\\&=e^{-a}\pi.\end{align}So,\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos^3(x)}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm dx&=\frac14\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(3x)}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm dx+\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{3\cos(x)}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm dx\right)\\&=\frac14\left(e^{-3}+3e^{-1}\right)\pi.\end{align}

Answer (score 6):

$$\hat f(\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)e^{-ix\xi}\,\mathrm dx \\
g(x)=e^{inx}f(x) \quad \quad \hat g(\xi)=\hat f(\xi-n) \\f(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}\quad\quad \hat f(\xi)=\pi e^{-|\xi|} 
$$

---

Using the identity you mentioned, and considering that $f\in L^1(\Bbb R)$, you have:
\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos^3x}{x^2+1}\mathrm dx&=\frac14\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos 3x+3\cos x}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx\\&=\frac18\int\left(\frac{e^{3ix}+e^{-3ix}+3e^{ix}+3^{-ix}}{1+x^2}\right)\mathrm dx\\&= \frac18\lim_{\xi \to 0}\left(\hat f(\xi-3)+\hat f(\xi+3)+3\hat f(\xi-1)+3\hat f(\xi+1)\right)\\&=\frac{\pi}{4}(e^{-3}+3e^{-1})\end{align}

Answer (score 5):

**Real Method**

As OP said, $$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos ^3 x}{x^2+1} d x 
= \frac{1}{4} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos 3 x+3 \cos x}{x^2+1} d x
$$
Let’s consider the parameterized integral,
$$
I(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (a x)}{x\left(x^2+1\right)} d x
$$
where $a>0$.
Then $$
\begin{aligned}
& I^{\prime}(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (a x)}{x^2+1} d x \\
& I^{\prime \prime}(a)=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x \sin (a x)}{x^2+1} d x
\end{aligned}
$$
Solving the differential equation
$$
\begin{aligned}
I^{\prime \prime}(a)-I(a) & =-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x \sin (a x)}{x^2+1}+\frac{\sin (a x)}{x\left(x^2+1\right)}\right) d x \\
& =-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\left(x^2+1\right) \sin (a x)}{x\left(x^2+1\right)} d x \\
& =-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (a x)}{x} d x \\
& =-\pi
\end{aligned}
$$
with the conditions that $I(0)=0$ and $I’(0)=\pi$, we have $I(a)=\pi-\pi e^{-a}$ and hence
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (a x)}{x^2+1} d x=I^{\prime}(a)=\pi e^{-a}
$$
We can now conclude that $$
 \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos ^3 x}{x^2+1} d x  =\frac{\pi}{4}\left(e^{-3}+3 e^{-1}\right)
$$

Answer (score 3):

$$ I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos^3(x)}{x^2 + 1} dx = \frac{3}{4} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2 + 1} dx + \frac{1}{4} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(3x)}{x^2 + 1} dx $$

$$ \cos^3(x)  =\frac{3}{4} \cos(x) + \frac{1}{4} \cos(3x)$$

Where the latter two integrals can be calculated by means of residues. See: [Fourier transform of a rational function using contour integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4820349/fourier-transform-of-a-rational-function-using-contour-integration)

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2 + 1} dx \to F_A(z)= \frac{e^{iaz}}{z^2+1}$$

With $a>0$. We have a simple pole at $+i$ inside our contour in the upper half plane:

$$ Res(F_A(z),z=i) = \frac{e^{-a}}{2i} $$

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty F_A(x) dx = 2 \pi i \frac{e^{-a}}{2i} = \pi e^{-a}$$
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2 + 1} dx = Re \Bigg( \int_{-\infty}^\infty F_A(x) dx \Bigg) = \pi e^{-a}$$

$$ I = \frac{3}{4} · \pi e^{-1} +  \frac{1}{4} · \pi e^{-3} = \frac{\pi}{4}(3e^{-1} + e^{-3}) $$

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for comment.*

You can avoid residues and Feynman trick for such a problem if you use the linearization
$$\cos^n(x) = 2^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \cos \big((2k-n)x\big)$$ which is valid for odd and even $n$ and the fact that
$$\frac 1{x^2+1}=\frac 1{(x-i)(x+i)}=\frac i 2\left(\frac{1}{x+i}-\frac{1}{x-i}\right)$$

Let $x=(t \pm i)$, expand the cosine to face
$$I_p=\int \frac {\cos(px)}{x^2+1}\,dx$$
$$2\,I_p=\sinh (p) \,(\text{Si}(i p-p x)-\text{Si}(p (x+i)))-$$
$$i \cosh (p) \,(\text{Ci}(-p (x-i))-\text{Ci}(p (x+i)))$$

$$J_p=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac {\cos(px)}{x^2+1}\,dx=\pi\,  e^{-|p|}$$